# Google Play Protect suddenly won't allow apk installation

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

The day before yesterday the application in which I work could be installed without errors in all the devices with which we work

Yesterday in some devices came a message from google play protect saying that the app was dangerous but allowed to install it

Today suddenly there is only one error saying that the app was not installed. And to install it you have to disable Google Play Protect on all test devices

The only important modification I can think of is that yesterday I had to format my computer installing unity 2018.2.6. The previous version was 2018.2.5

The app is not yet published and we are testing it by copying it by USB from device to device

Anyone know if there were major changes in Google Play Protect in the last few days, and how can I implement them in my APK to comply with the security guidelines and avoid further problems when publishing the App in the Store?

Answer (score 0):

you can test two way to resolve this problem:

1- change your sign and fill all fields in sign maker form,
2- contact with google play protect team and report this problem to them, you can use below link:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals
 after one or two days test again and try to install your app,if protect team resolve that problem you can install app without any dangerous message.

Answer (score 0):

You now (Android 10? and upwards) need to go into Settings > Security > Google Play Protect > Gear Icon (top right) > Turn off toggle.

Then you'll be able to install your APK. Be sure to see it's Information/Details and manually grant each permission that it may need.